# How to Build a Web Service Client from hosted .wsdl file?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl

I am trying to create a Web service client through Hosted wsdl file in visual studio but am unable to do it as am new to web services.
so does any one know, how to do this?

I tried it by adding service references.
also tried by Adding Command in Visual studio like

```
wsdl /l:CS /protocol:SOAP http://localhost/OIDServer/OIDServer.asmx?WSDL
```

but no use.

Comment: any error reported?

Comment: the error got reported while am using the command thing the error is
The term 'wsdl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.

Comment: If targeting a .asmx, you need to add a *Web Reference* instead of a *Service Reference*.

Comment: what's the error when adding web reference manually using visual studio?

Comment: actualy i just got a Url or the .wsdl file that is like
https://URL/Abc?wsdl
and i saved its source code with .wsdl and trying to add this file to my solution and that shows error like file can not be found after providing the physical location

Comment: and when am directly passing the URL that time it shiws error as like 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Draft//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error 500--Internal Server Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>

Comment: seems you don't know how to add web reference at all? have you ever succeeded adding web reference in other projects using the same steps?

Comment: yes,i did that with another .wsdl file and that is got added successfully but that is service reference not a web reference

Comment: and when am adding web reffrence by clicking on Advance Setting->Add web references and there am puting URL  then also i am getting the same error i.e 500 internal server error

Comment: when you paste the url to webbrowser and go, will you see wsdl contents page?

Comment: yes,but i think the url of wsdl file am using that  has some issues due to that it gives me error because  i tried the same with some other Url which i found on "http://quicksoftwaretesting.com/sample-wsdl-urls-testing-soapui/"  for a testing purpose i.e http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl and it is working properly with this i can also able to test its services.